# Writing to unaligned storage

Tags: c++, c++17, memory-alignment

I have some values that I want to write into a raw byte array, in exactly defined locations, to send them off over the network.

```
//These are computed somewhere else in the program (and converted to little-endian regardless of platform):
using float32_t = float; static_assert(sizeof(float32_t) == 4);
uint32_t someInteger = 42;
float32_t someFloat = 4.2f;
bool someBoolean = true;
uint16_t someIndex = 42, someCRC1 = 42;
```

My first solution worked and produced the right result, but the memory sanitizer warned me about unaligned writes:

```
char* data = someBuffer.data(); //points directly into allocated raw bytes
(*reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(data     )) = someInteger;
(*reinterpret_cast<bool     *>(data +  4)) = someBoolean;
(*reinterpret_cast<float32_t*>(data +  5)) = someFloat; //unaligned
(*reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(data +  9)) = someIndex; //unaligned
(*reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(data + 11)) = someCRC;   //unaligned
```

So I came up with this second solution by reordering some values and inserting a 1-byte buffer for alignment in between.

```
char* data = someBuffer.data(); //points directly into allocated raw bytes
(*reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(data     )) = someInteger;
(*reinterpret_cast<float32_t*>(data +  4)) = someFloat;
(*reinterpret_cast<bool     *>(data +  8)) = someBoolean;
(*reinterpret_cast<char     *>(data +  9)) = '\0'; //buffer for memory alignment
(*reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(data + 10)) = someIndex;
(*reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(data + 12)) = someCRC; //this has to be the last value!
```

However I would much rather have the first ordering and no alignment bytes. **Is that possible to do independently of platform or do I have to rely on having support for unaligned store instructions?** I've heard that maybe using `std::memcpy` may be able to do this but I am not sure if that's true and how I would use it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Does that also work on e.g. ARM where stores must be aligned?

Comment: It **is defined by the rules of the C++ standard**. That means any conforming C++ implementation must implement it correctly. `memcpy` is defined to copy data as if byte-by-byte, provided the source and destination do not overlap. So alignment is irrelevant. It copies bytes from one place to another. If the compiler can determine the source and destination alignment are satisfactory, it can use aligned load and aligned store instructions, respectively. If it cannot, it will use load-byte, store-byte, and/or other instructions as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::memcpy`, as in `std::memcpy(data + 5, &someFloat, sizeof someFloat);`. It is defined by the rules of the C++ standard, unlike using `reinterpret_cast` in the way shown in the question, and a good compiler will optimize it to simple load and store instructions if appropriate.

Note that the sizes of the objects being copied are dependent on the C++ implementation; it will be your responsibility to ensure they match the sizes as laid out in the buffer being sent. Also, the representations of objects are largely implementation-dependent, particularly the order in which their bytes are stored in memory, and so it is also your responsibility to make sure the representation matches what is expected in the message sent over the network. In some C++ implementations, you may need to reverse the bytes within objects. And you must ensure that the sending and receiving systems use the same format for `float`, and so on.

Comment: `In some C++ implementations, you may need to reverse the bytes within objects` Or reverse pairs of bytes - in theory. I suppose that there aren't many (or any?) middle endian C++ implementations in practice.

Comment: Nice, that works. I know about the sizes (thus uint32_t instead of unsigned) and the endianness (which I'm converting beforehand). The one thing I am assuming is that the implementation uses IEEE-754 for floats (which I don't know if any other implementations exist).